# Data Migration Assistant for PostgreSQL to migrate to Azure PostgreSQL (not DMS)

Tags: postgresql, data-migration, azure-postgresql

Whenever we migrate on-premises SQL to Azure SQL , we can use Data Migration Assistant (DMA) for assessment (and also Data Migration Service (DMS) for migration)

I know that we have DMS which can help in migrating on-premises PostgreSQL to Azure PostgreSQL

Do we have **Data Migration Assistant Tool** to migrate Postgres to Azure PostgreSQL PaaS (we want to assess before migration) ? Basically the need is to where the data is compatible to be migrated to Azure , before running the azure DMS

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there isn't a Microsoft's tool that execute the assessment for an on-premises PostgreSQL Database for Azure migration.
I think CloudPilot of UnifyCloud can be used.